# DolphinDB: How to change the first item of each row in an array vector?

Tags: arrays, arraylist, dolphindb

**[image: strong text]**

I want to replace the first item of each vector in column “B” with the corresponding value of column “A” while keeping other items unchanged. How to achieve this in DolphinDB?

Answer (score 0):

In DolphinDB, you can achieve this by using the set function along with the each function.
Example:

```
t = table(1 2 3, [4 5 6; 7 8 9] as B)
update t set B = B each {x[0] = A}
```

This code creates a table t with columns "A" and "B". Then, it uses the update statement to modify the values in column "B" using the each function. The lambda function {x[0] = A} is applied to each vector in column "B", setting its first element to the corresponding value from column "A".